# Problems downloading CSV file by pressing a unknown button on website

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I want to press what I thought was a simple button on a website to download a CSV file.
However, I cannot find the button to press in the HTML code and, if I can, it looks like it carries some parameters (if it is the class "input-group-addon btn").

I've done similar but limited stuff like this before, but this looks different. I can find other buttons to press on this website but not this one that downloads the CSV file. It does not contain a address to the file and it is definitely not a "normal" button. I struggle to find some info online that is not about either a link to the file address or a normal button.

```py
from selenium import webdriver
import time

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
options.add_argument("--test-type")
options.binary_location = "/usr/bin/chromium"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)

driver.get('https://www.tennet.eu/electricity-market/transparency-pages/transparency-germany/network-figures/actual-and-forecast-wind-energy-feed-in/')

text_area1 = driver.find_element_by_id('daterange')
text_area1.send_keys("print('23.05.2019 - 23.05.2019')")

submit_button = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('SOMETHING IN HERE')
submit_button.click()
```

Goal for this part of the script is to open site, input today's date in a textfield then press a button to download CSV file.

Comment: can you give us the source code of the submit button?

Comment: The button looks like it has no specific ID with which to access it. Id look to using the nth child button children of the form. It looks like theres only one form on that page.

The xpath for the button is //*[@id="dateForm"]/span[2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you could do it :

```
import time
text_area1 = driver.find_element_by_id('daterange')
text_area1.clear()
text_area1.send_keys("11.05.2019 - 12.05.2019")
#Wait for page to update
time.sleep(1)

#Click submit button
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.show-calendar .applyBtn').click()
time.sleep(1)

#Download file
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.icon-download').click()
```

**EDIT**
Using css selectors instead of xpath